# Doctrine 1.2 - Unknown record property / related component in a DQL with only 1 table envolved

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine, dql

I'm trying to execute this DQL:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('*');
->from('Clientes c');
$retorno = $q->execute();
```

My BaseClientes.php:

```
// Connection Component Binding
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->bindComponent('Clientes', 'padrao');

/**
 * BaseClientes
 * 
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
 * 
 * @property integer $pk_clientes
 * @property string $txt_nome
 * @property timestamp $ts_cadastro
 * @property string $txt_diretorio
 * @property Doctrine_Collection $Upload
 * 
 * @package    ##PACKAGE##
 * @subpackage ##SUBPACKAGE##
 * @author     ##NAME## <##EMAIL##>
 * @version    SVN: $Id: Builder.php 7490 2010-03-29 19:53:27Z jwage $
 */
abstract class BaseClientes extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('clientes');
        $this->hasColumn('pk_clientes', 'integer', 4, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'length' => 4,
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('txt_nome', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => 255,
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('ts_cadastro', 'timestamp', null, array(
             'type' => 'timestamp',
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('txt_diretorio', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'length' => 255,
             'fixed' => false,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             ));
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasMany('Upload', array(
             'local' => 'pk_clientes',
             'foreign' => 'fk_clientes'));
    }
}
```

My table SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE  `organizer`.`clientes` (
  `pk_clientes` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `txt_nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ts_cadastro` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `txt_diretorio` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk_clientes`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

When I execute this DQL, it returns to me:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Unknown record property / related component "clientes" on "Clientes"' in 
/var/www/organizer/lib/php/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Record/Filter/Standard.php:55 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/organizer/lib/php/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Record.php(1382):
 Doctrine_Record_Filter_Standard->filterGet(Object(Clientes), 'clientes') #1 /var/www/organizer/lib/php/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Record.php(1337): Doctrine_Record->_get
('clientes', true) #2 /var/www/organizer/lib/php/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Access.php(117): Doctrine_Record->get('clientes') #3 /var/www/organizer/lib/php/forger.php
(387): Doctrine_Access->offsetGet('clientes') #4 /var/www/organizer/app/clientes/model.php(20): forger->Table(Array) #5 /var/www/organizer/app/clientes/controller.php
(5): require_once('/var/www/organi...') #6 /var/www/organizer/web/index.php(9): require_once('/var/www/organi...') #7 {main} thrown in /var/www/organizer/lib/php/
doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Record/Filter/Standard.php on line 55
```

I really don't know what is happening, I have this same situation in other file of my system and work.

Please, someone help me....

OBS: Sorry my bad english, I'm Brazilian.

Comment: Try echoing the generated SQL-Query from the DQL with `echo $q->getSqlQuery();`

Comment: Thanks for the response Thomas,
The generated SQL-Query from DQL is: 

SELECT c.pk_clientes AS c__pk_clientes, c.txt_nome AS   c__txt_nome, c.ts_cadastro AS c__ts_cadastro, c.txt_diretorio AS c__txt_diretorio FROM clientes c

I've executed this SQL in MySQL Query Browser and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, but I've found the "error"...

What I need is only recover the data in an array, so I searched in Google and found this:

```
$con = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->connection();
$res = $con->execute("SELECT * FROM clientes;", array(1));
$retorno = $res->fetchAll();
```

And this solved my problem because I was trying to use the return of $q->execute() as an array...

PS: Sorry for misspell xD...